# Function to order numbers; find common difference and gap

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a vb6 function that will take up to 7 numbers, order them, find a common difference. There will be a gap in this sequence of numbers. I also want to identify the missing number.

Example input  is `19,17,20,and 16`. The output should be an array `16,17,18,19,20` in this order. Any help? I may be able to interpret vb.net code to vb6, but vb6 is preferred to me.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: You should post the code you've tried to get working so far, so we can evaluate it. If you haven't written any code yet, you should do that before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s an outline of what needs to be done:

- Find the smallest and largest number
- Create an array with enough entries to hold the full range from the smallest to largest
- Fill the array with the numbers from lowest to highest.

Note that you don’t need to sort the numbers at all. You just need to find the extreme values.

Here’s a code outline in VB6:

```
Function RangeFrom(ParamArray Numbers() As Long) As Long()
    Dim Lowest As Long
    Dim Highest As Long
    Lowest = Numbers(0)
    Highest = Numbers(0)

    Dim Number As Long
    For Each Number In Numbers
        If Number < Lowest Then Lowest = Number
        If Number > Highest Then Highest = Number
    Next

    Dim Result(0 To Highest - Lowest) As Long

    Dim I As Long
    For I = 0 To Highest - Lowest
        Result(I) = Lowest + I
    Next

    FromRange = Result
End Function
```

Comment: So if i find the max and min, how would i be able to find the missing number and put them in order? @konrad-rudolph

Comment: @ashraj98 - You don't need to find the missing numbers, because you don't care what numbers were missing originally.  All you need to do is create a new array from scratch and fill in all of the numbers.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try it @konrad-rudolph it seems to work for what I can see now thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged VB.NET as well, this should be convertible to VB6(i've avoided Linq):

```
Public Shared Function FillGaps(input As Int32()) As Int32()
    Dim output = New List(Of Int32)
    Array.Sort(input)
    ' now we'll find the min/max-values at the first/last indices
    For i As Int32 = input(0) To input(input.Length - 1)
        output.Add(i)
    Next
    Return output.ToArray()
End Function
```

Use it in the following way :

```
Dim intArray = {19, 17, 20, 16}
intArray = FillGaps(intArray)
```

Note that this approach  skips duplicates.

Comment: (This mutates the user input, which may or may not be a problem.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Are you referring to the duplicate issue(which you also have)?

Comment: No I’m referring to the fact that arrays are reference types and `Sort` will mutate the array.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Good point, a loop to find the min- and max-values is the better approach anyway. But i keep it as it is, otherwise it would get a copy of your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to mention it as a potential caveat, it certainly doesn’t invalidate this answer. It can also be mitigated (at extra cost) by copying the data.